# Is [馬面]{うまづら} a facial expression or a type of face shape?

Tags: translation, compounds

馬面 I found it translated as: `a horseface, a very long face; horse-faced, very long-faced`. Now here we call "long face" to be really sad. So in the translation, I don't know if 馬面 is referring to a facial expression of the face, or to some type of odd face shape people can have. Therefore my question is, is 馬面 an expression or a type of face?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched for the meaning in Japanese (googled 馬面の意味) and got the following:

> 馬の顔のように長い顔。

From this, I feel that it is safe to assume that by 'long face' they were talking about the physical shape of the face, not the English idiom.

For more information, I'd look at the following page:

https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A6%AC%E9%9D%A2

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/20301/meaning/m0u/

Especially with regards to the second source I've included, it should be noted that this term is considered to be a jeering comment.  Not that this is part of your question, but I would **NOT** use it to describe your significant other or close friends.